# Kotlin `null` is not `null`?

Tags: kotlin, null

This looks a little strange but I accidentally wrote this piece of code in Kotlin:

```
fun exchange(request: Request): ResponseEntity<*> = null!!
```

The IDE does not seem to be complaining. Is this allowed and if so why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The compiler is acting as if `null` has a type of:

```
ResponseEntity<*>?
```

Your !! operator is then telling the compiler to add a runtime cast to:

```
ResponseEntity<*>
```

From a compilation standpoint this is valid Kotlin, however at runtime it will always throw an NPE.

---

**Explaination**

Say you have the code:

```
var x : ResponseEntity<*>? = null
var y = x!!
```

Variable x has been defined be of type:

```
ResponseEntity<*>?
```

When you use the !! operator you are instructing the compiler that the returned type isn't nullable, therefore variable y is of type:

```
ResponseEntity<*>
```

This is valid code from a compilation standpoint, however at runtime it will fail with a NullPointerException, there is nothing unusual about this. Merging the lines together gives you:

```
var z : ResponseEntity<*> = null!!
```

You might be able to argue that the compiler should warn you that this code is probably incorrect (its a strange way to intentionally throw an NPE), however it is valid Kotlin.

Other than we are declaring a variable rather than a function (per your example) the reasoning why it compiles is identical.

PS Just for fun ;-) - if you wanted a shorthand for: `throw NullPointerException()` you could do:

```
if (someCondition)
    null!!
```

Comment: Slight nitpick: The compiler does not "infer" the type of `null`. `null` always have the type `Nothing?`. One is able to return `null!!` in this function because `Nothing` is the subtype of every type.

Comment: I have changed the phrasing to "acting as if" rather than saying "infer" I don't want to go down the rabbit hole of Nothing types in this answer.

Comment: Not sure if i would ever throw a NPE, but `null!!` throws NPE is a good thing to remember. Probably these are the kind of questions I would like to avoid asking in technical interviews.